# Name for when $R \cdot S \subseteq S \cdot R$?

Tags: notation, relations

is there a name for when for two relations $R,S$ on a set $A$ we have the property on the title? By $R \cdot S$ I mean the usual composition of $R$ and $S$ given by

$$ \{ (a,c) \mid \exists b. aRb \land bSc\} $$

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Thanks! I'm calling it "sequential commutation" (to distinguish it from the usual commutation in rewriting systems, which can be called parallel). In this case I say "S commutes *over* R".